# How to update membership status through importing

Tags: civimember

I am testing an import of a membership to update from "new" to "current".  I'm also trying to update the "end date" to be cleared.  Also the "membership type" to a different type.

When I do the import it overwrites only the membership type and nothing else.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe include some sample data that you are trying to import?

Comment: Second @Laryn, we need some more information on your data and membership type rules. Some thoughts that probably won't get you 100% of the way: 1) As far as I know, if your status conflicts with the membership type rules, it won't import. 2) Membership type is a match field, so you may need to import that change first and then import again with the new type in your csv. 3) Importing in general won't let you overwrite existing fields with blank so that may be going on with the end date.

Comment: Since rolling memberships don't allow blank dates, I'm assuming this is a fixed type.  As Eli said you can't really blank out the date.  I tried a few tricks to no avail.  You could set the end date to something way in the future.  If you really want it to be blank you could run simple sql afterwords to make the end_date null where it equals the way in the future date you used.

Comment: Well here's what I'm trying to solve: For whatever reason, the membership status does not move from "new" to "Current" after 30 days even though it seems to be configured that way.

2) we want membership to be ongoing forever unless someone specifically asks to stop membership (it's free on our site)

Comment: 3) There are over 250 records right now that have gone past the 30 day mark and still say "New" and have an expiration date of a year from first joined date... I set up a new membership type that is designated as "lifetime" and by default those new people have a blank expiration date field so I'm guessing that fulfills that desire to keep them members forever and that's why I was trying to just delete the others that have an expiration date.

Is there a better approach to these problems?